# Linux Permissions 604, do all users in the system have read to the file?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I have a question regarding linux permissions. If i set the permissions of a file to 604 all the users of the system will be able to read it?

I'm asking this because I was studying and that question came up, I though it was false, but the solution says it's true. If it is true can someone explain why? Does the others r permission override the group's?

Comment: No, the other permissions don't override group permissions. The owner gets the owner permissions, every in the group (except the owner) gets the group permissions, and everyone else gets other permissions.

Comment: To allow everyone to read the file, permissions should be 644.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [unix.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know
Permission: XYZ; where X for the owner, Y for Group, Z for other. 
Number: 4 for read, 2 for write, 1 for execute
Your permission set is 4+2,0,4. 
Now, if the owner is Nyan and group is buddy then Nyan could read and write, everyone from buddy group will not be able to read, write, execute. And other users can read only. Priority is from left to right, that's mean X> Y > Z